# Duplicate "large" div tag and put iformations in

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How do I create this `div` while I iterate over an `json array`?

I have different data which I would have to show in different thumbnails in a row and I'd like to have a template like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++)
{
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
           <div class="thumbnail">
               <img src="somesource" alt="sometext"/>

               <div class="caption">
                   <h3>jsonArray[i].title</h3>
                   <p>jsonArray[i].description</p>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
}
```

If anyone knows how to do this and which framework provides this, please help me out. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ng-repeat`feature of AngularJS
Just take a look at the example code I provided.

In your case, your variabele `jsonArray` would have to be assigned or replaced by `$scope.items`

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/xh4n4yyo/) to show a working example or just run the snippet

```js
var myApp = angular.module("example", []);

myApp.controller("exampleController", ['$scope', example]);

function example($scope)
{
    $scope.items = [
   {
         title: "Title 1",
            description: "This is a description for title 1"
        },
        {
         title: "Title 2",
            description: "This is a description for title 2"
        },
        {
         title: "Title 3",
            description :" This is a description for title 3"
        }
    ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="example">
  <div ng-controller="exampleController">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <img src="#" alt="some image"/>
        
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>
            {{item.title}}
          </h3>
          <p>
            {{item.description}}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  How can i change the array ?  I need a reuseable function to put a array in the function and this should been loop

Comment: whenever you change data in your array, $scope will pick up the change and update your data. You should read up on how to use arrays and maybe Angular and jQuery as well. Try some training courses and just practice. Questions like these aren't always answered, but you should at least try to do the coding yourself. We can lead the way, but won't solve everything.

Comment: and just as an example of what I mean with "$scope will pick up the change and update your data". Check this fiddle and add a new item. I just add it to my current array and it's added automatically in my html.